Is my dedicated server HD dying?
I have a dedicated server with 2 3TB SATA HDs. I use the server to create and share torrents. Recently I got the following error message when trying to create a torrent based on files on that server.
Notice: fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=5 Input/output error in /var/www/rutorrent/php/Torrent.php on line 449

The torrent creation is cancelled after this. What I did next was to boot the server in rescue mode and execute fsck. This led to some errors that were fixed.

As you can see in the screenshot there were errors like "inodes part of the orphaned inode list", and some other things that were fixed. I then rebooted the server and could create the torrent again. However, a few days later the same issue appeared again. And now I am a bit worried that there is an issue with my HD.
I therefore installed smartmontools and let it run with the following results of the 2 HDs. HD1 Smart results and HD2 smart results.
My question is: Are the fsck results concerning? Why did the error occur again? What do the SMART results say? And ultimately: Should I replace the HDs?

The fsck issues are a warning, certainly; they are an indication that the metadata for the file system is not getting reliably written to the disk, which can be a symptom of drive failure. But in your SMART results I note that HD1 shows 46,000 power-on hours and HD2 shows 70,000. That would indicate that HD1 has been running effectively continuously for six years, HD2 for nine. WD disks are good, but those are getting pretty long in the tooth; I'd plan to replace them very soon.

In addition to that, on one disk there are 4 "pending" sectors in a smart attributes, and the other has 3. These unstable sectors may be "fixed" by rewrite, and might be declared totally "bad" and relocated by the drive firmware. Yes, it looks like both disks are dying.
